# Deploying Jars from TFS to linux

Tags: maven, tfs, deployment, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Sorry if there was already a question for the subject but I couldn`t find it. 
I currently have a TFS (On-premise) Server Building a Maven project using an Agent installed on Ubuntu Machine.

The build is successful and the resulted Jar files are being published in the Artifacts tab on the build results.

Now, what is the next step if I want to deploy this jars to a different Linux server through SSH?

I read some articles  Stating I should use a Release Job in TFS, but could not find any working examples,

I assume I could execute a PowerShell/python script as a build step and get the jars to where I need them, but I really prefer to do it "Properly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to install an agent on the target machine, create a Release Pipeline Agent Phase that targets the specific machine and run a shell script to do with the artefacts whatever you want. The artefact will automatically be downloaded from the server as part of the agent phase.

Alternatively, you can run a Release Pipeline Agent Phase on your ubuntu box and use the sftp upload task to push the artefacts from the ubuntu agent to the target server. Then use the SSH task to shell into the server and do what it is you wanted to do.

Or you can ssh into the target server from your ubuntu box (using the SSH task) and then use curl or some other thing to download the artefact using the REST API.

Executing scripts is a very normal thing to do both in Release and in Build phases. You may need to put the scripts in a git repo or a central place to make sure they're accessible as part of the release workflow. You can also attach them as a second artefact to your build and then have them restored to the agent performing the release phase.